# AWS EC2のインスタンスのRegionを変更した場合、元の移行前のインスタンスは削除すべきですか？

Tags: amazon-ec2

AWS EC2でインスタンスのRegion変更/移行をしました。
アメリカ バージニアから EU フランクフルトに移行して、問題なくインスタンスのRegionを移行できたのですが、元のアメリカ バージニアRegionになっている古い方のインスタンスはterminateしても問題ないのでしょうか？

一通り検索はしましたが、それらしい情報が見当たらなかったので、もしご存知の方がおられましたらアドバイス、もしくは解決方法や該当リンクなど、教えていただけますと幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

terminateして問題ないと思います。
心配でしたらスナップショットを残してインスタンスは削除
しばらく経って問題なければスナップショットも削除すれば良いと思います。

Comment: お答えくださり、ありがとうございます。
参考にさせていただきます。